# How to toggle data showed in a table view

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app, I have a segmented control and a container in my ParentViewController. The container has a TableViewController in it called ChildTableViewController. I need to change the data in the table based on the the segmented control.

Question: I have a segment control action setup, but am unsure how to either reference the child to run reloadData() or somehow have a trigger that runs in the TableViewController when the segmented control is changed.

```
//MARK: IBActions
    @IBAction func segmentedControlAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    }
```

This code prints 0,1, or 2 based on which section I click on

Answer (score 0):

In your `segmentControlTapped` action method, you would get the `selectedSegmentIndex` property of the `UISegmentedControl`. Use this property value to switch the `dataSource` of your `tableView` like below:

```
switch selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: //Segment 1
          self.dataSource = /*update your dataSource here for Segment 1*/

    case 1: //Segment 2
          self.dataSource = /*update your dataSource here for Segment 2*/

    case 2: //Segment 3
          self.dataSource = /*update your dataSource here for Segment 3*/

    default: break

   /*IMPORTANT*/
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: So where does this go? The ChildTableViewController or the ParentViewController? Autocomplete doesn't find anything called selectedSegmentIndex in the ChildViewController.

Comment: For your `ChildTableViewController`s `tableView`.

Comment: Show me your `action` method for `segmentControl` and respected tableView

Comment: Change your `sender: AnyObject` to `sender: UISegmentedControl`

Comment: What does that do? That action triggers with the correct number. I just need to pass that number to the ChildTableViewController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115778/discussion-between-santosh-and-austin-erck).